# Can a sum of $n$ squares be expressed as the sum of $n/2$ squares?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, sums-of-squares, pythagorean-triples

The answer for the special case when the squares are Pythagorean triple is yes. The Pythagorean triples are the case of the lowest $n$, namely $2$. Two Pythagorean triples can be combined to form a sum of $4$ squares as in $(3^2 + 4^2) + (5^2 + 12^2) = 5^2 + 13^2$. Combining (adding) Pythagorean triples, we can make a sum of squares with arbitrary $n$.

Question: What happens in the general case when the pairs of squares involved are not Pythagorean triples or when not all pairs are Pythagorean?

Comment: Background: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_three-square_theorem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem

Comment: @ChrisCulter, the question is specific to the case where both the left and right hand side are sum of squares. The $2$, $3$ and $4$ squares cases deal with numbers that are not necessarily squares themselves.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. The immediate interpretation is "Suppose that for a positive integer $k$ we have $k = \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i^2$. Does it follow that also $k = \sum_{i = 1}^{n/2} b_i^2$?" The answer to that is by the links Chris Culter provided easily seen to be "No". But it seems that is not the question you intended. However, it is not clear which question you intended.

Comment: @DanielFischer, I am asking this question: Can a sum of $n$ squares be always expressed as the sum of $n/2$ squares? Using Pythagorean triples, the answer is yes since we can build a sum of squares with arbitrary $n$. But what about the general case (where we don't use Pythagorean triples). Your answer is no so if you can please make it into an answer. thanks.

Comment: I can't really unify that with your response to Chris Culter. Is it really the case that the fact that we can write for example $7 = 2^2 + 1^2 + 1^2 + 1^2$ as a sum of four squares but not as a sum of two squares already answers your question?

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, in this particular example you gave but I am not sure the answer is valid for any $n$.

Comment: The sum of two squares isn't always a square.

Comment: What do you mean by "valid for any $n$"? For every even $n > 0$ there are some sums of $n$ squares that can also be written as the sum of $n/2$ squares. If we allow $0$ as a square in the sums, then every positive integer can be written as the sum of four squares, and thus for every even $n \geqslant 8$ every number that can be written as the sum of $n$ squares can also be written as the sum of $n/2$ squares. If we disallow $0$ things get more complicated.

Comment: @DanielFischer, We disallow $0$ and we consider arbitrary $n$. I couldn't find any result when $n$ is large.

Comment: I still do not understand what you are asking.

Comment: @DanielFischer Here's an example that shows it's possible but only when using Pytagorean triples. $(3^2+4^2)+(5^2+12^2)+(8^2+15^2)+(7^2+24^2)=5^2+13^2+17^2+25^2$. That is a sum of $8$ squares can be equal to a sum of $4$ squares. But how about the general case with $n$ arbitrary and the squares not chosen from Pythagorean triples. I can give an example with $n=20$ and squares chosen among Pythagorean triples. But it's still not the general case.

Comment: An example of _what_? I still don't know what your constraints and parameters are. But, let me try this: For every $m \geqslant 5$, every sufficiently large positive integer (where "sufficiently" depends on $m$, but is relatively small) can be written as the sum of $m$ nonzero squares. Thus for even $n \geqslant 10$ every sufficiently large sum of $n$ squares can be written as the sum of $n/2$ nonzero squares. Thus for large $n$ there are only finitely many exceptions. But for $m \in \{1,2,3,4\}$ there are infinitely many positive integers that cannot be written as the sum of $m$ squares.

Comment: @DanielFischer, I meant I could give an example with $n=20$ squares that can be written as a sum of $10$ squares but only if I use Pythagorean triples. The part of your comment " Thus for even $n$ $\geq 10$ every sufficiently large sum of n squares can be written as the sum of $n/2$ nonzero squares.Thus for large n there are only finitely many exceptions." is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: HINT.- Take Pythagorean triples and $\sum(a_n^2+b_n^2)=\sum c_n^2$. The answer is YES.

Comment: @Piquito, what you wrote is basically what I said in the first sentence of my post. I know that if we use Pythagorean triples, the answer is yes and I even provided examples in the post and in one of my comments. The question is about the general case  when we are not using Pythagorean triples. The answer to that is not known for large $n$.

Comment: @user25406:- Sorry dear friend. I have the defect of not looking in detail at some problem statements. In any case I only want to help (when I can) solve problems for students. Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is **yes** for (even) $n \geq 8$ and **no** for (even) $n \leq 7$.

If $n \geq 8$ then the sum of your $n$ squares is the sum of four squares by the Lagrange four square theorem. Now, if $n/2$ is greater than 4, you can complete your sum by adding enough terms equal to $0^2$.

For $4 \leq n \leq 7$ note that $7$ can be written as the sum of $n$ squares but cannot be written as the sum of $n/2$ squares.

For $2 \leq n \leq 3$ note that $5$ is the sum of $n$ squares but not the sum of $n/2$ squares.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it is the more complete one. I was hoping to get an answer that does not allow the use of $0^2$ because allowing $0^2$ makes it trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Any two Pythagorean triples may be represented as the sum of four squares or the sum of two squares.

Examples:
$\qquad(15^2+8^2)+(21^2+20^2)=17^2+29^2$

or, from the example I showed in my first version of this answer:
$$157^2+12324^2=6493^2+10476^4=10147^2+6996^2=12317^2+444^2=12325^2$$
$\implies(157^2+12324^2)+(6493^2+10476^4)+(10147^2+6996^2)+(12317^2+444^2)\\\qquad\qquad\qquad=(12325^2)+(12325^2)+(12325^2)+(12325^2)$

where $8$ sums of squares are expressed as $4$.
I gave the example of $4$ equal values but any even number of any combinations of $C$-values can be reduced to half that number.

Another example is  here where $10$ square sums are equal to $5$ sums
$\qquad\qquad (3^2+4^2)+(5^2+12^2)+(13^2+84^2)+(85^2+132^2)+(157^2+12324^2)\\
\qquad\qquad=5^2+13^2+85^2+157^2+12325^2$

For your last question, if squares are not required, there are also infinite solutions:
$$(12+13)+(168+1)=5^2+13^2$$
or
$$(1^2+2^2)+(4^2+5^2)=(5+41)$$

Comment: Your answer is dealing with a different problem. What I want is in the question I asked, that is "can a sum of $n$ squares be expressed as a sum of $n/2$ squares. To get that for Pythagorean triples, we don't pick squares at random from a given triple. We just add a number $n$ of two squares on the LHS of a given triple and add them to get a sum of $n/2$ squares on the RHS like in this simple example: $(3^2+4^2)+(5^2+12^2)=5^2 + 13^2$. Here we see that $4$ squares add up exactly to $2$ squares. With Pythagorean triples, we can build cases like this for arbitrary large $n$.

Comment: So I will not be accepting your answer since it does not deal with the question as stated.

Comment: @poetasis it seems to me that it could be possible for the sum of positive integers $(A^2 + B^2 + D^2 + E^2)$ to equal the sum of positive integers $(C^2 + F^2)$ **without** the squares of any two of $\{A,B,D,E\}$ summing to either $C^2$ or $F^2$.  Assuming that my **supposition** (which may be in error) is accurate, you would not need pythagorean triplets involved in the answer.

Comment: @user2661923  I may have addressed your conjecture in an update to my answer.

Comment: @poetasis "I may have addressed your conjecture..." : I'm not sure
whether you have.  Let me clarify my supposition, with an explicit 
example.  Suppose you were given the following problem:
Do there exist positive integers A,B,D,E such that (for example)
$A^2 + B^2 + D^2 + E^2 = (101)^2 + (102)^2.$  Assume that there are
no positive integers A,B such that $A^2 + B^2 = (101)^2.$  This is
insufficient to conclude that the posed problem has no solutions.  ...see next comment

Comment: @poetasis
To the best of my knowledge, you would have to compute 
$z = (101)^2 + (102)^2,$ and then identify all ordered pairs
$(z_1, z_2)$ such that $z_1 + z_2 = z.$
Then, you would have to check each ordered pair $(z_1, z_2)$ 
**individually** to see whether there exist A,B,D,E such that
$A^2 + B^2 = z_1$ and $D^2 + E^2 = z_2.$  From this analysis,
consideration of pythagorean triplets would be only obliquely
involved in attacking the posed problem.

Comment: @user2661923, in fact we can build an infinite number of cases $A^2+B^2+C^2+d^2=E^2+F^2$. I gave an example and a method to do just that in a previous comment. 
Well, here's a counterexample to Deepak M S counterexample: $113=7^2+8^2=4^2+5^22+6^2+62=2^2+3^2+6^2+8^2$. We can in fact build many examples by combining the sum of two squares with that of four squares. In this case we start by choosing and adding 2 squares then calculate the sum of 4 squares for the resulting number. We get an infinite number of cases.

Comment: @user25406 I'm sorry, I'm not grasping how your comment relates to the specific sample problem that I posed.  Given the Diophantine $A^2 + B^2 + C^2 + D^2 = [(101)^2 + (102)^2],$ my previous comments outline a long-winded attack that examines all possible values of $(z_1, z_2).$  Can you re-express your ideas into a method that would streamline attacking the specific sample Diophantine that I have posed?

Comment: @user2661923, I don't think we are talking about the same thing. What I said is not relevant to solving your Diophantine equation. I said that given $2$ squares, we can always add them to get an integer that we can then express as a sum of $4$ squares. And in this particular case, we don't really need to go through Pythagorean triples.

Comment: @user2661923.  There are two triples $\quad (9401,3960,10201)\land (5796,8640,10404)\quad$ where the hypotenuse is either $101^2$ or $102^2$.

Here, we have $$(9401^2+3960^2+5796^2+8640^2)=101^4+102^4$$

If you are just looking for $101^2$ and $102^2$ we have

$$(99^2+20^2+90^2+48^2)=101^2+102^2$$

Comment: @user25406 not all squares can be expressed as the sum of $4$ squares unless you include trivial terms like $1^2$ or $2^2$.

Comment: @poetasis, I don't have a problem with using $1^2$ and $2^2$, as long as we avoid $0^2$.

Comment: @user25406 Perhaps I wasn't clear.  I was just offering $A^2 +B^2 +D^2 + E^2 = (101)^2 + (102)^2$ as a **sample** problem, with a long-winded attack involving examing all possible positive integer values $(z_1, z_2)$.  Here, the only constraint on $z_1, z_2$ is that $z_1 + z_2 = [(101)^2 + (102)^2].$  The whole point is, can any analysis be brought to bear that streamlines attacking the general Diophantine, where 101 and 102 are replaced by any positive integers.  The approach I've shown is very cumbersome and inelegant.  **Does analysis provide a better approach to the general Diophantine?**

Answer (score 0):

From Lagrange's four square theorem, we have that every natural number can be expressed as the sum of four perfect squares.  Because we can always add $0^2$ without changing the sum, this means that every natural number can be written as the sum of $n$ squares for any $n\geq4$.

Your problem asks if given that $M$ is the sum of $n$ squares, can it be written as the sum of $\frac{n}{2}$ squares.  As this requires that $n$ be even, we have four cases:

Case 1: $n=2$

In this case, given that $M$ is the sum of two squares, it is only the sum of one square if we have a Pythagorean triple.

Case 2: $n=4$

In this case, $M$ can be any natural number.  The question asks if a generic natural number can be written as the sum of 2 squares.  The answer to this question comes from the Sum of Two Squares Theorem, credited to Euler, and says that a number can be written as the sum of two squares if and only if its prime factorization doesn't contain a prime that is congruent $-1\mod4$ raised to an odd power.

Case 3: $n=6$

In this case, M can be any natural number.  The question asks if a generic natural number can be written as the sum of 3 squares.  From Legendre's Three-Square Theorem, the answer is that most, but not all natural numbers can be written as the sum of three squares.  Specifically, all natural numbers but those appearing in [this OEIS sequence](https://oeis.org/A004215) can be written as the sum of three squares

Case 4: $n\geq8$

In this case, every natural number can be written as the sum of $\frac{n}{2}$ squares, and therefore the answer is trivially yes.

For the Cases 3 and 4, we have enough leeway in choosing $n$ squares that we can choose a breakup that does not include any Pythagorean Triples

Comment: I think OP mentioned (in the comments under the question) that adding $0^2$ as a term was not allowed.

Comment: @DeepakMS, $0^2$ not allowed precisely because it make the problem trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I understand the question correctly, because if this is what you actually mean, then it is not too difficult to come up with counter examples.

My interpretation : Given a collection of $n$ positive integers, $\{ a_1, ..., a_n \}$, it is possible to find a collection of $n/2$ positive integers, say, $\{ b_1, ... , b_{n/2} \}$ such that $$ \sum_{i=1}^{n} {a_i}^2  = \sum_{i=1}^{n/2} {b_i}^2 $$.

If this is what you actually mean, first consider $n$ to be an odd integer and we are done. Because $n/2$ is not an integer the statement is obviously false.

Now suppose $n$ is only allowed to be even. Consider, say $n = 2$ and $a_i = 1$ for both $i=1,2$. $\sum {a_i}^2 = 1^2 +1^2 = 2$, not a perfect square, and is thus a counterexample to the statement.

Comment: we are talking about squares. I am not sure if considered that.

Comment: Sorry for the typo.  Edited now.

Comment: yes there are many counterexamples but we cannot conclude that a sum of $n$ squares can never be a sum of $n/2$ squares unless we use Pythagorean triples.  I would like a more general result if possible and preferably a proof to show under what conditions it is possible (or impossible).

Comment: @DeepakMS I second user25406's comment.  In particular, see my comment to poetasis' answer.

Comment: Well, here's a counterexample to your counterexample: $113=7^2+8^2=4^2+5^2+6^2+6^2=2^2+3^2+6^2+8^2$. We can in fact build many examples by combining the sum of two squares with that of four squares. In this case we start by choosing and adding $2$ squares then calculate the sum of $4$ squares for the resulting number. We get an infinite number of cases.